# How to enable the Account.users editable or how to delete or editor a user of Meteor.users()?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

I use meteor and the package of accounts-password and alanning:roles. 
The issue is when I try to use the role admin to delete or editor another accounts. 
I want make the users can editable. 
The result is always:

```
remove failed: Access denied. No allow validators set on restricted collection for method 'remove'.
```

I try to use the common way to allow the users can be editable, but failed.

```
Accounts.users.allow({
'insert':function(userId, doc){

  return true;
},
'update': function (userId, doc) {
    return true;
},
'remove': function (userId, doc) {
    return true;
},
'download': function (userId, doc) {
    return true;
}
});
```

The fail of them is:

```
W20160203-09:46:40.136(11)? (STDERR) C:\Users\sheng\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.10\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:245
W20160203-09:46:40.136(11)? (STDERR)                                            throw(ex);
W20160203-09:46:40.136(11)? (STDERR)                                                  ^
W20160203-09:46:40.136(11)? (STDERR) Error: allow: Invalid key: download
W20160203-09:46:40.136(11)? (STDERR)     at packages/mongo/collection.js:746:1
W20160203-09:46:40.136(11)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (packages/es5-shim/.npm/package/node_modules/es5-shim/es5-shim.js:417:1)
W20160203-09:46:40.136(11)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/underscore/underscore.js:105:1)
W20160203-09:46:40.137(11)? (STDERR)     at [object Object].addValidator (packages/mongo/collection.js:744:1)
W20160203-09:46:40.137(11)? (STDERR)     at [object Object].Mongo.Collection.allow (packages/mongo/collection.js:792:1)
W20160203-09:46:40.137(11)? (STDERR)     at server/permissions/permissions.js:15:14
W20160203-09:46:40.137(11)? (STDERR)     at G:\work\sb-admin\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\app\server\permissions\permissions.js:41:4
W20160203-09:46:40.137(11)? (STDERR)     at G:\work\sb-admin\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:242:10
W20160203-09:46:40.137(11)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20160203-09:46:40.137(11)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\sheng\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.10\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
```

Comment: `download` is not a valid key... there is [insert, update, and remove](https://devdocs.io/meteor/index#allow)

Answer (score 1):

Download isn't a valid key, which is why you're seeing the error.  You're likely thinking it's a valid key because CollectionFS has it.

https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS#security